# How do I serialize a JBox2d World object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, objectoutputstream, jbox2d

I have a server that has several clients connecting.  Each client has one body (player) that they can control but there can be collision therefore they will need to see everyone else's body to know why some of their movement is restricted.

My solution is to pass the "World" object over a object in/out stream. Then I parse and draw each body using processing.  Here is the error I'm getting:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jbox2d.dynamics.World
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at Client.setup(Client.java:30)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2280)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:243)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2176)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jbox2d.dynamics.World
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at Player.sendWorld(Player.java:57)
    at Server.draw(Server.java:54)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2305)
    ... 3 more
```

Obviously World needs to be serialized/serializable before it can be passed over the socket.  Any idea how I would do that?  Will I need to do the for each body, create xml/json then pass that instead of simply sending the world?

**Server Out**

```
public void sendWorld(World world) {
    try {
        out.writeObject(world);
        out.flush(); // or maybe out.reset()
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Client In**

```
try {
    bodySocket = new Socket(serverHostname, port);
    in = new ObjectInputStream(bodySocket.getInputStream());
    Object next = in.readObject();
    System.out.println("Getting world");
    if (next instanceof World) {
        this.world = (World) next;
    }
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverHostname);
    System.exit(1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: "
            + serverHostname);
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Client Draw**

```
public void draw() {
    // Background
    background(100);
    // Bodies (includes floors, walls, and players)
    for (Body body = world.getBodyList(); body != null; body = body
            .getNext()) {
        Vec2 playerLoc = body.getPosition();
        rectMode(PApplet.RADIUS);
        fill(255, 100);
        rect(playerLoc.x, fieldBottom - playerLoc.y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I can't figure this out soon, I may end up iterating through the world body list and creating a json object to hold the user data, coords and object types of each body.  Would be more networking efficient but not as easy to write.

Answer (score 2):

I made the serialization package for this reason :)

I include serialization to protobufs, which is probably the best thing for you (it reduces the size the most).  You can serialize worlds, bodies, joints, shapes, whatever granularity you want.

Check out [PbSerializer](https://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/jbox2d-serialization/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/serialization/pb/PbSerializer.java)

and here is documentation on protobufs:
https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work. All documentation with examples appears to be for c++ and not java.  I tried several things and ended up giving up.  There should really be a page like they have for C# that gives not only the methods available but a short example of how to use them.

Comment: The documentation is in C++ and Java, check again:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial
:)

Or more importantly, you don't really have to worry about making the protocol buffer, as I've already done this.  Just use the PbSerializer  and PbDeserializer classes I made in the jbox2d-serialization package.

Comment: Thanks for writing back.  I took a look at the page you linked to but didn't really see any examples on serialization in Java.  Maybe I just missed it.  I did see a few methods but not how they are used and what they expect.  I did try the PS & PD classes but when I finally got it to compile, my object writer would pass it.  I ended up writing my own JSON parser but I'd love to see a skeleton example of a world object passed from server to client!  I'm curious if you decide to send a string or an object over the socket.

Comment: The protobuf objects have serialization methods to bytes, it's very efficient and compresses really well.  I would really look into learning about them, they're a great tool that will serve you well (they're very popular in the industry as well).  What do you mean "my object writer would pass it"?

Also, all you have to do is call build() on the world that you serialize, and then you can do something like "toByteArray()" or something like that, take a look at the protobuf javadoc for the best serialization method.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the JBbSerializer class. From it's javadoc: "Serializer for jbox2d, used to serialize any aspect of the physics world," so it might do what you're looking for. Look for it in the jbox2d-serialization project (that should have come with your download). It may be more trouble than it's worth, though.

Comment: Thanks, this may work... PbSerializer pbs = new PbSerializer(); Builder obj = pbs.serializeWorld(world); and then on the client     if (next instanceof Builder) {
     this.world = pbd.deserializeWorld((PbWorld)next);